# Reset/clear viewmodel or livedata

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-navigation

I am following the *one-single-activity* app pattern advised by Google, so if I want to share data between `Fragments` I have to share a `ViewModel` whose owner must be the parent `Activity`. **So, the problem becomes because I want to share data between only two Fragments, independently from the others.**

Imagine I have  `MainFragment`, `CreateItemFragment` and `ScanDetailFragment`. So, from first one I navigate to CreateItemFragment in which whenever I press a button I navigate to  ScanDetailFragment in order to scan a barcode and, in consequence, through a `LiveData` object inside the ViewModel I can get the scanned value back into the CreateItemFragment once ScandDetailFragment finishes. The problem becomes when I decide to cancel the creation of the item: I go back to the `MainFragment' and because the ViewModel's owner was the Activity's lifecycle, once I go again into CreateItemFragment, the previously scanned value is still there.

**Any idea to reset that ViewModel?**

Comment: Instead of sharing the same view-model I suggest you pass the data between fragments instead. This directly solves your problem without complicated logic and and conforms more to single responsibility principle (each view-model takes care of its own view). As an alternative override onBackPressed() and reset the view-model before transitioning to the previous fragment.

Comment: but, aren't Viewmodels also aimed to share data between different views? Otherwise I do not know how to pass data back from fragment C to B... and how can I reset the viewmodel?

Comment: A view-model is a model for a specific view, so sharing a single view-model between different views defeats the purpose of the view-model, as well as makes changes and logic in the view-model more complicated than necessary (your problem is an example of unnecessary complexity). You can pass data between fragments using navigation component ([this is how I do it](https://github.com/m0skit0/inhaler/blob/main/app/src/main/java/org/m0skit0/android/inhaler/view/history/PunchHistoryFragment.kt#L45)). To reset the view-model just create a `reset()` method and call it from the fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but, aren't Viewmodels also aimed to share data between different views?

No. Each viewmodel should be responsible for one view. The "shared viewmodel" pattern is for cases when you have one large view (i.e., activity) that has multiple subviews (i.e., fragments) that need to share data / state, like [the master / detail example in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing). It's a convenience for these cases when you need real-time updates amongst the subviews.

In your case, you're *navigating* between fragments and as such should be *passing data* through the transitions. This means [passing arguments along when starting new fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data?hl=en) and [registering for results when they complete their task](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result).

Then each of your fragments is isolated, self-contained, more easily testable and you won't end up with a God-ViewModel that does All The Things™ and turns into a giant mess as you try to jump through hoops accounting for every state it could possibly be in.

Comment: Exactly, well explained.

Comment: Thank you both @m0skit0 and dominicoder. So checking your links, I've seen there are several options: integrate a ViewModel into a nested navigation graph or using FragmentManager listener. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with @dominicoder. At this [link](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0), you can find a Codelab made by the Google team updated to Oct 30, 2021. The shared `ViewModel` pattern can be used when you need a coherent flow to achieve a specific task inside your app.

This method is useful and a good practice because:

- The Jetpack team says that has never been a recommended pattern to pass Parcelables. That's because we want to have a single source of truth.
- Multiple activities have been heavily discouraged for several years by now ([to see more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU)). So even though you're not using Jetpack compose, you still should use a shared `ViewModel` along with fragments to keep a single source of truth.

Downside:

- You need to reset all the data manually. Forgetting to do so will bring bugs into your app, and most of the time, they're difficult to spot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks in such cases to share data between fragments. or if you use DB/Sharedpreference/Content provider then you do not have to worry about sharing data each page will fetch its own data from the store(DB/SharedPreference/Contentprovider).

you can also try https://medium.com/@lucasnrb/advanced-viewmodels-part-iii-share-a-viewmodel-between-fragments-59c014a3646 if this guide helps

Comment: from the store? what to you mean?

Comment: I think he means data repository (from an MVVM architecture point of view)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear `LiveData` value every time when you go into `CreateItemFragment` from `MainFragment`.

Or you can just clear it from the `CreateItemFragment` in `onBackPressed()` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you cancel the creation of item,set livedata value to  null.then  within observer code if(updatedvalue!=null) write your code using updated live data value.in this way you can avoid last updated value.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (on 2022), the method `viewmodel.getViewModelStore.clear();` or `onCleared();` **is deprecated**.

So, if you want to clear data holded by ViewModel or clear value of LiveData, you just need use 1 line code like this:

```
mainViewModel.getLiveData().getValue().clear();
```

- getLiveData() is my method inside MainViewModel class to return `liveData` variable
- getValue() is defaut method provided by LiveData (MutableLiveData: setValue(), postValue())

If you need to clear data when user press on Back button in Fragment, you can do like the code below & put it inside the **onViewCreated** method - the method of LifecycleFragment.

```
private void handleOnBackPressed() {
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                Objects.requireNonNull(mainViewModel.getLiveData().getValue()).clear();
                requireActivity().finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

*My project on Git if you want to refer code (it still updated):* https://github.com/Nghien-Nghien/PokeAPI-Java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/pokemonapi/fragment/MainFragment.java